# sqlite quoted column name still case non sensitive (feature or bug)

Tags: sqlite

I discovered this:

```
create table yo ([I] integer, [i] integer)
SQL error 1 : duplicate column name: i
```

Is this a feature or a bug? I read in [the doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) that we can quote column name.

I am writing code that is not DB portable (Using `SQLITE_` name space everywhere) so is there a non-standard DB option setup that can make sqlite engine case  sensitive.

I know purist will say that having 2 cols with the same name is non sensical, but I have situation where case in column names are derived from languages where case sensitivity makes sense.

Cheers,

Phi.

Answer (score 3):

In SQLite, identifiers are never case sensitive, not even when quoted.

For backwards compatibility, this is considered a feature.

Comment: Thanx CL for your prompt reply. How much an effort would it be to have an optional option (pragma, meta command?) that break this backward compatibilty, since I start working with sqlite there is no background for me, and turning an option doesn't break past programs? I am not fluent enough to evaluate how much of a works it is to change the "identifier compare" function.

Comment: If you need to ask, then the effort would be too large for you. :)

Comment: Sounds the sqlite3AddColumn() ==> STRICMP() could be hacked, if a glob is set (in do_meta() .ident_case_sensitive=1) then sqlite3AddColumn() can do an strcmp(). Don't have time to investgate if that is enough

Comment: SQLite identifiers *are* case sensitive when it comes to non-ASCII identifiers... e.g., there is no problem running the following Cyrillic (with a single letter in either case): `CREATE TABLE yo ([Б] integer, [б] integer)`. See also http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18